# Google Cloud IOT, block communication via API

Tags: google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-iot

I'd like to block communication with a device in a registry in Google Cloud IOT.

The gcloud command that is used to block communication: https://cloud.google.com/iot/docs/gcloud-examples#block_or_allow_communication_from_a_device

The [Patch API](https://cloud.google.com/iot/docs/reference/cloudiot/rest/v1/projects.locations.registries.devices/patch) doesn't make it clear how one can block communication of a device using the API

So how is this achieved?

Answer (score 0):

There is [an example snippet for patching a device](https://cloud.google.com/iot/docs/samples/device-manager-samples#iot-core-patch-device-ec-python) available that may be helpful for you.

Instead of sending a EC value in the patch body, you could update the device to have communication blocked.

In Python, you would do this as:

```
client = get_client(service_account_json)
registry_path = 'projects/{}/locations/{}/registries/{}'.format(
        project_id, cloud_region, registry_id)

patch = {
    'blocked': 'True'
}

device_name = '{}/devices/{}'.format(registry_path, device_id)

return client.projects().locations().registries().devices().patch(
        name=device_name, updateMask='blocked', body=patch).execute()
```